# changing position of stacked histogram R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, data-visualization

I used the following code:

```
ggplot(adult, aes(age)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill= income), color= 'black', binwidth = 1) + theme_bw()
```

To generate this plot:

[image]

My question is how do you change the stacked position for the plot to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the order of factor levels of `income` variable before plotting

```r
#reorder fill variable
adult$income <- with(adult, factor(income, levels(income)[2:1]))
```

```
#plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(adult, aes(age)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill= income), color= 'black', binwidth = 1) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Output plot is:

[image]